# How to resolve error when installing gensim?

Tags: python, gensim

I'm trying to install gensim on Windows 7, with Python 3.4. According to [gensim official installation tutorial](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html), gensim depends on NumPy and SciPy, so I went to [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) to download .whl files for NumPy and SciPy installation. But when I used pip to install them, it gave me these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
import gensim
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gensim\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from gensim import parsing, matutils, interfaces, corpora, models, similarities, summarization
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gensim\matutils.py", line 21, in <module>
import scipy.linalg
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 172, in <module>
from .misc import *
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
from .blas import get_blas_funcs
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in <module>
from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。
```

"找不到指定的模块"means "Cannot find the designated module".
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy and Scipy can be pretty difficult to install, because they rely on some classic implementations of algorithms in older programming languages like Fortran, which have complicated dependency chains.

Would you be amenable to installing [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda), a fantastic Python distribution that includes Numpy and Scipy? If you install Anaconda's python installation, you should find it easy to use `pip install gensim` because you'll already have the most difficult-to-install dependencies installed.

There are Python 2.7 and 3.5 versions [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_windows) if you'd like to give it a try. As someone who regularly uses Numpy and Scipy, I regularly install Anaconda on new machines and it saves lots of heartache!

Comment: The official tutorial of Gensim also said "Windows users are well advised to try the Enthought distribution, which conveniently includes Python & NumPy & SciPy in a single bundle, and is free for academic use". Is [Enthought distribution](https://store.enthought.com/) also an option here?

Comment: Yes indeed @joewong, I've also used Enthought Canopy, but have come to prefer Anaconda for its great package management system (Anaconda has a `conda install {package}` cli that's similar to Python's pip, Node's npm, Ruby's gem, etc.). Either Enthought Canopy or Anaconda should be a great base platform on which to build.

Comment: okay but I have already downloaded Python 3.4 for almost two months now. Also I'm working on a business project for the company and I don't think it's worth changing environments, which means I might lose all the work I've done... Couldn't I just use binary packages and compile them? Though I'm well aware SciPy has complicated dependencies...

Comment: Yes of course you can install Numpy and Scipy from scratch. It'll take some fortran compilers and some patience. If you're worried about losing the libraries you've installed, you can use `pip freeze` to find what you've installed, then write a script to reinstall those libraries. As someone who's worked with Numpy and Scipy for several years now, I <i>highly</i> recommend that you consider an Anaconda installation. Worst case, you could install Anaconda on another box, e.g. an EC2 instance, and leave your local machine untouched.

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try... Hope it works 'cause when I found out SciPy itself depends on libraries like ATLAS and BLAS and uses a bunch of compilers... drives me crazy... anyway really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, one must really go down the rabbit hole to get those libraries installed. Recent Mac OSX installations ship with scipy and numpy installed, which is great, but Windows users must struggle to take care of these dependencies. Enjoy Anaconda!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I was trying to install spacy and gensim using pip in Pycharm console. I solved this problem following the next steps:
1. Download Python 3.5 and configure it as interpreter of your project (remember, maybe you have other versions of Python, make sure you choice 3.5 for your project)
2. USE PIP AND CMD TO INSTALL THE LIBRARIES YOU NEED. If you use the Pycharm terminal, the installation may fail.

Use CMD instead of native Pycharm terminal solved my problem. I hope this can help you.